# Is it possible for a type 3 civilisation to use a blackhole bomb to stop a gamma ray burst?

Tags: physics, stars, weapon-mass-destruction, black-holes

A gamma-ray burst can be caused for multiple reasons. Some of the more common ones is that either a supermassive star undergoes a supernova and collapses into a black hole, two neutron stars collide, or a neutron star and a blackhole collide. In most cases, it involves a star. To avoid the first scenario, maybe some civilisations can starlift the star to reduce the mass, prevent the supernova explosion. To avoid the latter, a type 3 civilisation could build a caplan thruster on both stars and push them away. However, both are quite time consuming and might not offer a decent solution if these advents are going to happen sooner rather than later. This is why I am wondering if a blackhole can be used to blow up the stars before they undergo a supernova.

A black hole bomb requires a black hole to be surrounded by mirrors positioned outside of its ergosphere. For a civilization capable of constructing a Dyson sphere, this task could be relatively straightforward due to the smaller scale involved. When an electromagnetic wave is directed at the mirror, a fraction of it will be absorbed by the black hole's event horizon, but a larger portion will be amplified due to the black hole's rotation. This triggers superradiant scattering. If the accumulated energy is not released, the mirrors will eventually fail, resulting in the release of energy comparable to a supernova.

For more information, check [this video from Kurzgesagt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulCdoCfw-bY&t=463s) out.

For a bit of context, putting a blackhole right next to a Neutron star to remove the star's mass will not work, since Neutron stars and blackhole collisions are a source of Gamma ray burst. This is why the blackhole bomb would be used instead, to try to blow up the star before it collides.

To help make things clearer, the blackhole will not be created, nor will it be moved to a star. In the scenario which the question is about, a blackhole and a star are going to collide in each other and cause a gamma ray burst. The closer they get, the faster they orbit each other making slow methods like caplan thrusters useless. This is why they would build a mirror around the blackhole to blow up the star next to it so that there isn’t a gamma ray burst. Just letting the blackhole next to the star be, will not stop the gamma ray burst and also the blackhole is already spinning so all one has to do is to build a mirror around the ergosphere and shot an electromagnetic wave into the sphere of mirror surrounding the blackhole to start the superadiant scatter progress.

Would exploding a blackhole bomb next to a star which is soon going to supernova stop the GRB (Gamma ray burst)? Or would it maybe cause some other bad side effects such as causing the star to explode sooner or stopping the GRB, but being as bad as one... ?

Answer (score 2):

A black hole bomb sounds like overthinking. If you can make a portable, quickly growing black hole that will last without caring, you could just put it near the sun and consume it (if the black hole doesn't collapse immediately), averting a supernova. Expect the outcome for any other bodies in the system to be ugly if you haven't prepared.

Fortunately, your black hole will only need to reduce the star to one similar in mass to ours. After that, it will not go supernova.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what a blackhole bomb is. It does not suck up the star, but instead it amplifies electromagnetic waves, until they break the mirror surrounding the ergosphere and cause a massive explosion. Having a blackhole right next to a Neutron star will not solve the issue, but instead would cause a GRB. https://www.space.com/gamma-ray-origin-black-hole-neutron-star-collision & https://phys.org/news/2022-07-merger-black-hole-neutron-star.html